# select value to show another hidden dropdown box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this code for a [website](http://shumoni.com/testing/quotations.php) I am working on, but it does not work:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select[name="Discount"]', function() {
    var $select = $(this);
    var $partnerBlock = $select.closest('.col-md-2').siblings('.partner');
    if ($select.val() === 'Yes') {
        $partnerBlock.addClass('show');
    }  else {
       $partnerBlock.removeClass('show');
    }
});
```

What I want is hide the Partner dropdown by default, hiding it from everyone, and show it only when user set Discount to "Yes".

Comment: Ok, and where is problem? Check what this selector returns: closest('.col-md-2').siblings('.partner'); btw, use find('.partner'), rather... And i can't see class partner in your html (maybe i am wrong)...

Comment: And closest() will find closest parent, so, it will not return desired element...you maybe want to use next('.col-md-2').find('your select element'). If this doesn't help, post your code in snippet...

Comment: use var `$partnerBlock =  $('select[name=Partner]');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide it by default and then use an event listener on the `change` event for the dropdown.

https://jsfiddle.net/mco1sxcb/

You should use ids for your elements, easier to manipulate them.